# .rules accessor error on changing networking layer for Knative Serving

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine, knative, knative-serving

**Describe the bug**
On moving away from Contour to Kourier for networking layer, Knative Serving cannot be reconciled due to the follow error.

```
{"severity":"ERROR","timestamp":"2023-07-12T19:21:03.858540009Z","logger":"knative-operator","caller":"controller/controller.go:566","message":"Reconcile error","commit":"ff7e841-dirty","knative.dev/pod":"knative-operator-7b56d8c589-qrglj","knative.dev/controller":"knative.dev.operator.pkg.reconciler.knativeserving.Reconciler","knative.dev/kind":"operator.knative.dev.KnativeServing","knative.dev/traceid":"b3490531-8a0b-400e-8546-c20ac6a1d547","knative.dev/key":"knative-serving/knative-serving","duration":"36.766091ms","error":".rules accessor error: <nil> is of the type <nil>, expected []interface{}","stacktrace":"knative.dev/pkg/controller.(*Impl).handleErr\n\tknative.dev/pkg@v0.0.0-20230418073056-dfad48eaa5d0/controller/controller.go:566\nknative.dev/pkg/controller.(*Impl).processNextWorkItem\n\tknative.dev/pkg@v0.0.0-20230418073056-dfad48eaa5d0/controller/controller.go:543\nknative.dev/pkg/controller.(*Impl).RunContext.func3\n\tknative.dev/pkg@v0.0.0-20230418073056-dfad48eaa5d0/controller/controller.go:491"}
{"severity":"INFO","timestamp":"2023-07-12T19:21:03.858665466Z","logger":"knative-operator.event-broadcaster","caller":"record/event.go:285","message":"Event(v1.ObjectReference{Kind:\"KnativeServing\", Namespace:\"knative-serving\", Name:\"knative-serving\", UID:\"479b26af-a4f8-43f0-a490-1481874e89b8\", APIVersion:\"operator.knative.dev/v1beta1\", ResourceVersion:\"1873540919\", FieldPath:\"\"}): type: 'Warning' reason: 'InternalError' .rules accessor error: <nil> is of the type <nil>, expected []interface{}","commit":"ff7e841-dirty","knative.dev/pod":"knative-operator-7b56d8c589-qrglj"}

Unable to obtain the installed manifest; obsolete resources may linger.rules accessor error: <nil> is of the type <nil>, expected []interface{}
```

**Expected behavior**
Contour controller scaled down, and Kourier components deployed.

**To Reproduce**
Have not been able to reliably reproduce in a different environment.

**Knative release version**
v1.10

**Additional context**
Following is my KnativeServing CRD. Prior to this, it was `spec.ingress.contour.enabled: true` and `spec.config.network.ingress-class: "contour.ingress.networking.knative.dev"`. Following this change, the aforementioned error repeats even on reverting the change and attempting to restore contour use. I have also attempted deleting the entire Knative stack and redeploying, with similar results.

```
apiVersion: operator.knative.dev/v1beta1
kind: KnativeServing
metadata:
  name: knative-serving
  namespace: knative-serving
spec:
  version: "1.10"
  ingress:
    kourier:
      enabled: true
  config:
    deployment:
      max-non-active-revisions: "1"
      min-non-active-revisions: "1"
    network:
      ingress-class: "kourier.ingress.networking.knative.dev"
    autoscaler:
      pod-autoscaler-class: "kpa.autoscaling.knative.dev"
      enable-scale-to-zero: "true"
```